# Question on sylow application

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Without using the generalized cayley theorem prove there is no simple group $G$, of order $112$.

Answer: If we can find a pair of distinct  sylow $2-$ subgroups $A$ and $B$ such that $|A\cap B|=8$, then $N(A \cap B)\geq AB$ so that $N(A \cap B)=G$.

Why does this first statement hold here $?$ Why does $A,B$ being sylow $2$ subgroups such that $|A \cap B|=8$ imply $N(A \cap B)$ contains the subgroup $AB$? $N$ is the normalizer of subgroup in $G$.

Comment: $8$ sylow $7$ subgroups

Comment: Oops, quite right. Messed up my mental arithmetic...

Comment: Note that there is no assertion that $AB$ is a subgroup; but we know that its size as a subset is $|A||B|/|A\cap B|$, which under the given assumptions, would be $2^8/2^3 = 2^5$. That means that the normalizer is a subgroup and contains at least $32$ elements... and so must be equal to all of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are Sylow-2 subgroups and their intersection has order $8$, then $AB$ *cannot* be a subgroup: its size is
$$|AB| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|} = \frac{(16)(16)}{8} = 32,$$
which does not divide $|G|$.

But in fact, the statement does not claim that $AB$ is a subgroup, and you do not need that. The normalizer contains both $A$ and $B$, because $A\cap B$ is normal in each (being of index $2$). And since the normalizer contains both $A$ and $B$, it contains the *subset* $AB = \{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$. That means that the normalizer contains at least $32$ elements, which in turn implies it must be all of $G$, since its order must divide $|G|$.